# Is there any list of which PMS spot colors are reproducible in CMYK?

Tags: color, cmyk, color-conversion, color-spaces, pantone

Is there any list of which PMS spot colors are reproducible in CMYK?

And a list of which Pantone colors are out of gamut for CMYK?

Comment: You need a CMYK swatchbook, on the same paper stock as you are using. That is the only way to ensure color accuracy. TRUMATCH is exclusively CMYK. From the website: "The TRUMATCH 4-color matching system was designed by applying the logical organization of Hue/Saturation/Brightness (HSB) to process color. There are 50 hue families shown in the order of the spectrum, with 40 perfectly proportioned tints and shades of each hue plus a selection of 4-color greys -- over 2,000 colors in all. The smooth, precisely proportioned steps take the guesswork out of 4-color selection and matching."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pantone inks cover substantially wider range of colors than common CMYK processes when compared as printed on the same paper and watched in the same light conditions, so there's no way to find a CMYK equivalent for every Pantone ink. In addition you should specify the used CMYK process or actually its color profile. What CMYK color is equivalent with a certain Pantone color cannot be answered without that spec. The result is totally different with different CMYK processes and often no equivalent CMYK even exists.

I said when compared as printed on the same paper and watched in the same light conditions. That's essential! In bright light and printed on a highly reflective white paper CMYK printing can produce wider range of seen colors than the whole Pantone ink list when they are watched in dim light.

See this Pantone guide https://www.pantone.com/articles/color-fundamentals/understanding-different-color-spaces.

Unfortunately Pantone color data is proprietary. Pantone color catalogs are commercial products. They have many different catalogs available: Color books for color selection, color bridge for conversion to most common CMYK and RGB, conversion book to Pantone's own extended 7-color printing system and formula quide for mixing Pantone colors of Pantone's base inks.

Popular programs like Indesign can get today a plugin "Pantone Connect" which connects to Pantone's online catalog and creates to you a swatch of a selected Pantone ink number and also equivalent CMYK numbers (if exists in your current CMYK work profile). Such plugin must be hired separately. it's not a part of Indesign. In the past Adobe's programs had quite big Pantone color libraries, but they are no more included in recent versions.

The plugin gives also CIELAB (Lab in Photoshop) numbers of the wanted Pantone spot color when watched in a certain standard illumination. If you have Photoshop you can instantly check if that Lab color is printable in your current CMYK process. Turn the gamut warning and proof colors ON.

There exists 3rd party tools which give some hints, like "input your CMYK or RGB number and the allowed color measurement difference number, we calculate which Pantone inks are within that difference". Here's one free: https://www.ginifab.com/feeds/pms/cmyk_to_pantone.php

It's not especially useful as is, because it assumes your CMYK printing is as capable as your sRGB screen in producing different colors. In addition it cannot know all Pantone ink mixtures. But it can still be interesting. Pantone itsef also provides the same kind of info for free in its website.

The linked site contains some links to other sources. Do not expect there's an on-the-screen full substitute of a Pantone color book. Such item cannot exist, because normal sRGB screens cannot show all Pantone colors.

You asked a list of CMYK-reproducible Pantone spot colors. Pantone's color bridge is the closest one which you can get as paper. As said, it's a commercial product.

Comment: Interesting link. It would be also interesting to compare to actual color bridge data.

Comment: The removal of pantone color list from adobe software has really shown how saas is not a good thing for customers. If we still had actual versions pantone and adobe could not have done this stunt.

Comment: Thanks! I'll try out the different suggested methods.

Comment: I strongly believe that Pantone changes its values from time to time just to stay relevant. Some years ago there were charts for conversion. They disappeared when the color bridge guide was introduced. Now they are blurred from the website.

Comment: @joojaa, hear hear. But you can't easily copy the .acb files from an older version to the new to get the color books back. But of course they won't get updated anymore.

Answer (score 0):

PMS colors are reproducible in CMYK because Pantone has a bigger color space.

You can buy the [CMYK COLOR GUIDE SET - COATED & UNCOATED](https://www.pantone.com/products/graphics/cmyk-color-guide-coated-uncoated) from Pantone to get the Pantone colors in the CMYK color space.